# What does ARC stand for in terms of Linux time concepts?

Tags: linux, time

Under Linux (Fedora 20), there is a file at `/etc/sysconfig/clock` looking like as follows:

```
ZONE="America/Denver"
UTC=true
ARC=false
```

What does ARC stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`false` indicates that the normal UNIX epoch is in use. The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970

`true` indicates the ARC console's 42-year time offset is in effect. This setting is only for ARC- or AlphaBIOS-based Alpha systems.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-clock.html

Answer (score 3):

It indicates that the normal [UNIX epoch](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-clock.html) is in use.

[image]